# Given a text file with file names, how can I find files in subdirectories of the current directory?

Tags: bash, find

I have a bunch of files with different names in different subdirectories. I created a txt file with those names but I cannot make `find` to work using the file. I have seen posts on problems creating the list, on not using `find` (do not understand the reason though). Suggestions? Is difficult for me to come up with an example because I do not know how to reproduce the directory structure.
The following are the names of the files (just in case there is a formatting problem)

```
AO-169 
AO-170 
AO-171
```

The best that I came up with is:

```
cat ExtendedList.txt | xargs -I {} find . -name {}
```

It obviously dies in the first directory that it finds.

I also tried

```
ta="AO-169 AO-170 AO-171"

find . -name $ta
```

but it complains `find: AO-170: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: what would be the ideal outcome of the operation? A file with the full path of the desired files from your list?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! the above line returns the names with a single quotation in front.

Comment: @inverzeio I need to cp those particular files

Comment: Perhaps your file has DOS line endings. What's the output of the command `file ExtendedList.txt` ?

Comment: ```ExtendedList.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators```

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings indeed. Remove the carriage return characters: `tr -d '\r' <  ExtendedList.txt > ExtendedList.txt.new` and use the new file.

Comment: Thanks! Now I do not have the trailing characters. However, doing ```cat ExtendedList.txt | xargs -I {} find . -name {}``` still does not do what I want.

Comment: "does not do what I want".  What is it you want?  What exact output do you require?  Because if I try your command with a list of files to find on my system, I do get an output of those files.  It you are getting directories and files, you could discriminate further on the `find` with `-type f` to get only files.

Comment: I want to cp those files somewhere else. But if I run the line above, I do not get anything as I would using ```find``` <- meaning I do not get the results in the prompt.

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is a poor way to communicate what you do want. I second the suggestion to [edit] to try to clarify what you want the code to do.

Comment: @Nic3500 I would expect a syntax error if you passed in a list of more than one file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to ask "how can I find files with any of these names in subdirectories of the current directory", the answer to that would look something like

```
xargs printf -- '-o\0-name\0%s\0' <ExtendedList.txt |
xargs -r0 find . -false
```

The `-false` is just a cute way to let the list of *actual* predicates start with "... or".

If the list of names in `ExtendedList.txt` is large, this could fail if the second `xargs` decides to break it up between `-o` and `-name`.

The option `-0` is not portable, but should work e.g. on Linux or wherever you have GNU `xargs`.

If you can guarantee that the list of strings in `ExtendedList.txt` does not contain any characters which are problematic to the shell (like single quotes), you could simply say

```
sed "s/.*/-o -name '&'/" ExtendedList.txt |
xargs -r find . -false
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option is throwing the following error ```printf: illegal option -- o```. The second option using ```sed``` is finding some of the files. I guess is breaking because some weird character in between.

Comment: Oh duh, thought I had fixed that `printf` already - my apologies; please reload.

Comment: "Some weird characters in between" is not much to go on. If you can isolate to an actual [mre] we can probably figure that out too.