# Given an array with filenames, how to find and delete all matching files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

Given a blacklist.txt file with filenames:

```
.picasa.ini
Thumbs.db
._.DS_store
```

How can I best find files with those filenames and delete them? I tried:

```
readarray -t blacklisted < ./Blacklist.txt
for n in ${blacklisted[@]};do find . -type f -name "${n}" -delete; done
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work for me" mean? Your attempt is kind of inefficient and the lack of quoting would break if you have file names with spaces etc in them, but your example input doesn't exhibit that problem. Demo of no repro: https://ideone.com/NOuApo

Comment: This is eerily similar to this very recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350619/given-a-text-file-with-file-names-how-can-i-find-files-in-subdirectories-of-the/70364976?noredirect=1#comment124384454_70364976

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line, and launch the rm command on each iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='blacklist.txt'
echo Start
while read p; do 
    echo "removing $p ..."
    find . -name "$p" -exec rm {} \;
done < "$filename"
```

Add the -f flag to the rm command if you feel confident.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP's attempt didn't work. A better solution would build a list of predicates and only run `find` once.