# GNU Bash Running Find with Concatenated String

Tags: bash

I'm using a file to pass in paths to exclude from a find. I can generate the command and run it fine from the command-line but when I try to execute it from the script I get an error.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nots=$(while read line; do
  echo -n "-not -path \"*/${line}/*\" "
done < exclude_directories.txt)

echo $nots

echo "Run this command:"
echo "find ~/files -type f $nots > ~/files.txt"

find ~/files -type f $nots > ~/files.txt
```

When I run the script the find command return every file - even those specified in the `nots`.

Here's the output with set enabled:

```
$ ./dump_all_local_repo_files.sh

nots=$(while read line; do
  echo -n "-not -path \"*/${line}/*\" "
done < exclude_directories.txt)
++ read line
++ echo -n '-not -path "*/.git/*" '
++ read line
++ echo -n '-not -path "*/vendor/*" '
++ read line
++ echo -n '-not -path "*/external/*" '
++ read line
++ echo -n '-not -path "*/node_modules/*" '
++ read line
++ echo -n '-not -path "*/test/*" '
++ read line
+ nots='-not -path "*/.git/*" -not -path "*/vendor/*" -not -path "*/external/*" -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -not -path "*/test/*" '

echo $nots
+ echo -not -path '"*/.git/*"' -not -path '"*/vendor/*"' -not -path '"*/external/*"' -not -path '"*/node_modules/*"' -not -path '"*/test/*"'
-not -path "*/.git/*" -not -path "*/vendor/*" -not -path "*/external/*" -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -not -path "*/test/*"

echo "Run this command:"
+ echo 'Run this command:'
Run this command:
echo "find ~/files -type f $nots > ~/files.txt"
+ echo 'find ~/files -type f -not -path "*/.git/*" -not -path "*/vendor/*" -not -path "*/external/*" -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -not -path "*/test/*"  > ~/files.txt'
find ~/files -type f -not -path "*/.git/*" -not -path "*/vendor/*" -not -path "*/external/*" -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -not -path "*/test/*"  > ~/files.txt

find ~/files -type f $nots > ~/files.txt
+ find /Users/ken/files -type f -not -path '"*/.git/*"' -not -path '"*/vendor/*"' -not -path '"*/external/*"' -not -path '"*/node_modules/*"' -not -path '"*/test/*"'
```

Comment: consider prefacing the code with `set -xv` (debug mode), run the code, update the question with the debug output so we can see what's in `$nots` and the actual `find` command that's being executed

Comment: Please add command which runs fine from command-line to your question (no comment here).

Comment: sooo `-path '"*/.git/*"'` do you see the problem? No, quoting by putting `"` inside a string is invalid, `"` has no effect there.

Comment: I do see that now. Echo doesn't add the single quotes.`-path "*/.git/*"` works fine.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70364976 for some ideas you could try.

Answer (score 1):

Does your version of `find` really support a `-not` operator? Usually it is spelled `!`.

To find all non-directories you would use

```
find . \! -type d
```

You also should remove the quotes in

```
find ~/files -type f "$nots"
```

since with the quotes there's no word-splitting. That said,

```
 nots=$(while read line; do
   echo -n "-not -path */${line}/* "
   done < exclude_directories.txt)
 find ~/files -type f $nots > ~/files.txt
```

should work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I can run the command fine in the shell but it fails in the script.

Comment: @user3063045 No you can't, you're running a different command. The following will not work and elicit the exact error you posted: `nots="-not -path foo"; find . "$nots"`. The first problem is the double quotes.

Comment: I've updated the question. Removing the quotes allows me to run the command but find returns everything instead of everything minus the nots.

Comment: @user3063045 You should also remove the backslash/double quotes in `\"*/${line}/*\"`.

Comment: Removing the backslash/double quotes in \"*/${line}/*\" worked! Please update the answer.

Comment: @user3063045 Wonderful! I've updated the answer.